# How to create MTOM enabled web service client in java using eclipse IDE

Tags: web-services, apache, mtom

i am using cxf 2.0 web services .I am publishing one web service which will send the file as an attachment as response . For doing this i am making my web service MTOM enabled set to TRUE using spring configuration . Now i want to generate a web service client using eclipse IDE which will consume above web service . So how can i make this web service client so it will be able to receive the attachment ?